# cannot figure out how to complete the sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, database-schema

I am currently studying for a database exam in a few weeks and in the past paper they supplied (without answers) is giving me some issues.

I'm concerned about the questions below because I have nothing to check against if i'm approaching them the right way, so I was wondering if anyone here could take a look and help me out? Have I answered them in the right way?

Thanks...

There are 3 tables in the following schema,

```
Suppliers (sid(PK):integer, sname:string, address:string)
Parts (pid(PK):integer, pname:string, color:string)
Catalog (sid(PK):integer, pid:integer, cost:real)
```

The catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by suppliers.

I have the following questions and my answer is below:

1. List the pnames of parts for which there is some supplier

   ```
   SELECT pname
   FROM Parts, Catalog
   WHERE Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
   AND Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
   AND Catalog.sid NOT NULL;
   ```
2. Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part or a green part

   ```
   SELECT sid
   FROM Catalog, Parts
   WHERE Catalog.pid = Parts.pid 
   AND Parts.color = 'red' 
   OR Parts.color = 'green';
   ```
3. Find the sids of suppliers who charge more for some part than the average cost of that part (averaged over all the suppliers who supply that part)

   ```
   SELECT sid
   FROM Catalog
   WHERE cost > (AVG(cost));
   ```

Comment: there's no need to repeat the WHERE statement. It starts with `WHERE`, and all further conditions are added with the `AND` or `OR` operators.

Comment: Okay thanks for that tip, I wasn't sure if I had to say it again. Other than that, does it look right?

Comment: hmm, all the tables you are using in conditions (WHERE) or SELECT, must be included in the FROM statement, joined together if there are more than one.

Comment: Okay I have now changed it to include those tables in the FROM statements. Anything else? (thanks so much so far)

Comment: I remember this struggle.... Here's how to approach it. Get all the data from the tables with an INNER JOIN (it's in your book). Then filter the data with WHERE.

Comment: it looks better, take care of AND conditions blent with OR conditions. OR does not prevail, you have to use parenthesis. Also, the third query is totally wrong, you should read a bit more about aggregates and GROUP BY instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my best shot at answering, but I haven't tested it out yet**

List the pnames of parts for which there is some supplier

```
SELECT pname
FROM Parts
WHERE 
Parts.pid NOT IN
  (SELECT Catalog.pid FROM Catalog);
```

Find the sids of suppliers who supply a red part or a green part

```
SELECT sid
FROM Catalog, Parts
WHERE Catalog.pid = Parts.pid 
AND (Parts.color = 'red' 
OR Parts.color = 'green');
```

Find the sids of suppliers who charge more for some part than the average cost of that part (averaged over all the suppliers who supply that part)

```
SELECT sid
FROM Catalog c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT pid, AVG(cost) AS avg_cost
 FROM Catalog
 GROUP BY pid) c_avg ON c.pid = c_avg.pid AND c.cost > c_avg.avg_cost
ORDER BY c_avg.avg_cost DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm a little confused by the Parts.pid NOT IN part. 

Are you saying where the pid in Parts is not in the pid in catalog? Wouldn't you need to see where there are no suppliers?

Comment: I am trying to say that if the Part has no Suppliers then its `pid` will never show up in the statement `SELECT pid FROM Catalog`. The Catalog table seems to be linking Suppliers to Parts.
If you haven't learnt about nested queries yet then your lecturer is probably expecting a different solution

Answer (score 0):

You can practice here.... 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

It's a skill that will be very helpful to you even if you don't become a DBA.